# Emails aren't sent in Wordpress with headers

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email, contacts

I'm running a new WordPress website on LEMP on Debian 7, sendmail installed.

I have a custom theme installed which has contact form.

Contact form says email sent but email actually not delivered. I have tried to remove `$headers` from email, email delivered. Simple php mail function working properly. Same custom theme sending and delivering email through form at Shared host.

**Here is part of custom form:**

What is wrong with this? can anyone point me out what is wrong or how I can start sending emails?

```
if(!isset($hasError) && ($correct == true)) {

    $admin = get_bloginfo('admin_email');
    $portfolio = get_bloginfo('name');
    $portfolio_url = home_url();

    $emailTo = $admin;
    $pro = get_the_title();
    $subject = "You have an message for $pro";
    $body = "Hello,\r\n\r\nYou've received an message from ".$name.", for ".$pro." fun name.\r\n\r\nHere are message details:\r\n--------------------------------\r\nBuyer Name: ".$name."\r\nEmail: ".$email."\r\nMessage: ".$message." ".$CurrencyCode."\r\n\r\nMessage: ".$message."\r\n\r\n---------\r\n".$portfolio."\r\n".$portfolio_url;
    $headers = "From: ".$portfolio." <".$emailTo.">" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: " . $email;

    wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

    $emailSent = true;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Print out your headers and make sure things like `$portfolio` don't have invalid special characters.

Comment: `$portfolio` has simple Blog name.

Comment: Any `"` or `<` or whatnot marks in it? Again, `print $headers` somewhere and put the results here.

Comment: If anything wrong with it, it should not send mails on shared host. Sendmail has default configuration.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_mail` has an open [bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21659) related to the `Reply-To` header. Try removing that header only and check if the email is sent correctly. If that's the case, you will have to create a plugin to wrap it or just avoid setting the `Reply-To` header.

Comment: If I use like `wp_mail($emailTo, $subject, $body]);` It send emails. but with headers it doesn't. Even I removed `Reply-To:` part.

Comment: Then the $emailFrom must be the issue.